# Limit of a sequence of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Let $\left\{Y_n\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of random variables, $Y_n \text{ i.i.d. } Z\equiv N(0,1)$. I want to find the limit of:
$$K_n=\sqrt{n}\:\dfrac{Y_1+\cdots+Y_n}{{Y_1}^2+\cdots+{Y_n}^2}$$

I tried using $\frac{1}{n}\left(Y_1+\cdots+Y_n\right)\longrightarrow 0$ and $\frac{1}{n}\left({Y_1}^2+\cdots+{Y_n}^2\right)\longrightarrow 1$, and then using that $K_n$ is similar to the definition of Student's T but then I didn't get anywhere.

Comment: Well, if you know about the Student's $t$ distribution, you already have it.

Comment: I have just realized it. It is really easy. Thank you so much

Comment: For the limit, you can forget Student and use that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(Y_1+\cdots+Y_n\right)\longrightarrow Z$ in distribution and $\frac{1}{n}\left({Y_1}^2+\cdots+{Y_n}^2\right)\longrightarrow 1$ almost surely.

Comment: Did you follow my hint? With which result?

Comment: @Did Using Slutsky Theorem I get $K_n\longrightarrow \frac{Z}{1}=Z$

Comment: You might want to post this as an answer.